# Including Jasmine-node files in Karma's runner

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, jasmine-node

Currently I have a set of node.js Javascript files along side a set of "regular" Javascript files that I will send down to a browser, using Angular as the client side framework. For unit testing I am using jasmine-node to test the server and am using jasmine via Karma for my client side files.
Is there a way I can include my jasmine-node files into Karma to have a single test runner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have a node.js server with angular.js client code and am using jasmine-node. I do not know if there is a way (or if it is even desirable) to use jasmine-node to test your client code. I am using karma (which is formerly testacular) and it works beautifully. All you need to do is create a config file that loads your project and angular.mock.js and points to your test files.

I'm sorry this doesn't exactly answer your question but it is a painless testing method.

http://karma-runner.github.com/0.8/index.html

Comment: I put Karma in place to test my client side files, what would be ideal is if I could run my Server side tests using it. I will update my question reflect that.

Comment: I havn't found a satisfactory way to get karma to run Jamine-node tests therefore I am going to use Karma and have two different test runners